# Kafka consumer partition rebalance when there are more consumers than partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Lets say initially we have a topic with 3 partitions and a consumer group with 3 consumers that consumes from this topic. If we add one more consumer to the consumer group, does a partition rebalance occurs? I know one of the consumers will be inactive since there is only 3 partitions but I am not sure about the rebalancing.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache Kafka, consumer groups are designed to allow a group of machines or processes to coordinate the consumption of messages from one or more topics. When you have a topic with a certain number of partitions, those partitions are distributed among the consumers in the consumer group to balance the load.

When you add another consumer to an existing consumer group, Kafka indeed triggers what is known as a "rebalance". This rebalance process is a way for Kafka to redistribute the partitions among the available consumers in the consumer group. The goal is to ensure that the message consumption load is evenly distributed among all consumers.

In Apache Kafka, consumer groups are designed to allow a group of machines or processes to coordinate the consumption of messages from one or more topics. When you have a topic with a certain number of partitions, those partitions are distributed among the consumers in the consumer group to balance the load.

When you add another consumer to an existing consumer group, Kafka indeed triggers what is known as a "rebalance". This rebalance process is a way for Kafka to redistribute the partitions among the available consumers in the consumer group. The goal is to ensure that the message consumption load is evenly distributed among all consumers.

Here's what happens when you add an additional consumer to a consumer group with an existing number of consumers and partitions:

1. The new consumer joins the group, causing a group membership change.
   Kafka detects this change and initiates a rebalance operation.
2. During the rebalance:

   a) All consumers in the group stop consuming messages.

   b) Kafka redistributes the partitions among all consumers in the group, including the new one.

   c) The consumers then resume consuming messages from their newly assigned partitions.
3. After the rebalance:

   a) Each consumer will be consuming from one or more partitions, depending on the total number of partitions and consumers.

   b) In your specific case with 3 partitions and now 4 consumers, one consumer will end up without an assignment and will be idle, as there aren't enough partitions for all consumers. However, it remains part of the consumer group, ready to take over consumption of a partition if one of the other consumers goes down or if more partitions are added to the topic in the future.

The rebalance ensures that the message consumption workload is evenly distributed across the consumer group and that the system can adapt as consumers are added or removed. It's an automatic process managed by Kafka to maintain effective load balancing and fault tolerance within consumer groups. This process is crucial for scaling and managing consumers efficiently in a Kafka cluster.